# How to add ano more measure of interest in the arules package

Tags: arules

I would like to add two additional measures  as a results of the "inspect" function in arules package. They are Kulczynski and imbalance ratio.
Would you help me with info, where to find the code of inspect function and how to modify it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to add additional columns to the quality data.frame. Inspect will automatically pick those up. Here is the example from `? interestMeasure`:

```
data("Income")
rules <- apriori(Income)

## calculate a single measure and add it to the quality slot
quality(rules) <- cbind(quality(rules), 
  hyperConfidence = interestMeasure(rules, method = "hyperConfidence",
     transactions = Income))

inspect(head(sort(rules, by = "hyperConfidence")))

  lhs                                 rhs                                support confidence     lift hyperConfidence
1 {ethnic classification=hispanic} => {education=no college graduate} 0.1096568  0.8636884 1.224731               1
2 {dual incomes=no}                => {marital status=married}        0.1400524  0.9441176 2.447871               1
3 {occupation=student}             => {marital status=single}         0.1449971  0.8838652 2.160490               1
4 {occupation=student}             => {age=14-34}                     0.1592496  0.9707447 1.658345               1
5 {occupation=student}             => {dual incomes=not married}      0.1535777  0.9361702 1.564683               1
6 {occupation=student}             => {income=$0-$40,000}             0.1381617  0.8421986 1.353027               1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. To calculate the Kulczynski and imbalance ratio I need to use a single itemset support of each interesting transaction.For example the Imbalance ratio is equal to |sup(A)-sup(B)|/(sup(A)+sup(B)-sup(A->B))

Answer (score 3):

Imbalance is quite straight forward:

```
library(arules)
data("Income")
rules <- apriori(Income)

suppA <- support(lhs(rules), trans = Income)
suppB <- support(rhs(rules), trans = Income)
suppAB <- quality(rules)$supp
quality(rules)$imbalance <- abs(suppA - suppB)/(suppA + suppB - suppAB)

inspect(head(rules))
  lhs                                 rhs                               support confidence     lift  imbalance
1 {}                               => {language in home=english}      0.9128854  0.9128854 1.000000 0.03082862
2 {occupation=clerical/service}    => {language in home=english}      0.1127109  0.9292566 1.017933 0.69021050
3 {ethnic classification=hispanic} => {education=no college graduate} 0.1096568  0.8636884 1.224731 0.61395923
4 {dual incomes=no}                => {marital status=married}        0.1400524  0.9441176 2.447871 0.35210356
5 {dual incomes=no}                => {language in home=english}      0.1364165  0.9196078 1.007364 0.63837280
6 {occupation=student}             => {marital status=single}         0.1449971  0.8838652 2.160490 0.34123127
```

The Kulczynski measure 1/2(P(A|B)+P(B|A)) is a little more tricky. P(A|B) is just the confidence of A->B. However, for P(B|A) we need the confidence for B->A. So we need to create a new set of rules with the left-hand side and the right-hand side switched and calculate confidence:

```
 confAB <- quality(rules)$conf
 BArules <- new("rules", lhs = rhs(rules), rhs = lhs(rules))
 confBA <- interestMeasure(BArules, method = "confidence", trans = Income)
 quality(rules)$kulczynski <- .5*(confAB + confBA)

 inspect(head(rules))
    lhs                                 rhs                               support confidence     lift  imbalance kulczynski
  1 {}                               => {language in home=english}      0.9128854  0.9128854 1.000000 0.03082862  0.9564427
  2 {occupation=clerical/service}    => {language in home=english}      0.1127109  0.9292566 1.017933 0.69021050  0.5263616
  3 {ethnic classification=hispanic} => {education=no college graduate} 0.1096568  0.8636884 1.224731 0.61395923  0.5095922
  4 {dual incomes=no}                => {marital status=married}        0.1400524  0.9441176 2.447871 0.35210356  0.6536199
  5 {dual incomes=no}                => {language in home=english}      0.1364165  0.9196078 1.007364 0.63837280  0.5345211
  6 {occupation=student}             => {marital status=single}         0.1449971  0.8838652 2.160490 0.34123127  0.6191456
```

Comment: Just an update. Imbalance, the Kuliczynski measure and many other measures are now available in the function  `interestMeasure`.

Comment: are these measures available to use in sequence rules (by the arulesSequences package?